# Why does my C# MVC4 web application get certificate warnings when the certificate is installed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-7.5

I have a web application that I've built and deployed to a Windows 2008 R2 server hosted on IIS 7.5. I'm using an API that is making restful service calls to a different application. I know that I am getting SSL Certificate errors because when I use this code to suppress them it works fine:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
               ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

What doesn't make sense is that I have the certificate that is required installed on the remote machine. Before I had the certificate installed, I could navigate to the test Restful service URL for the other application and get certificate error. So I installed this certificate error to the Trusted Root and that error went away. However, my web application must still be getting the error. When I add the above mentioned code everything is working perfectly fine.

Does IIS 7.5 have settings that I can set for Certificates, does my web application have configurations where I can change this behavior? I don't understand the default behavior, my expectation is that since the certificate is installed in the trusted root my web app on that server would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the certificate in the Machine or Registry store so that the IIS application pool identity can pick it up. If you install it in the User store, your browser will see it and use it but since ASP.NET runs under a different identity, it will not be able to use it.

Comment: Can you provide details on how to install the certificate in the machine or registry stores? I only know of 1 way to install certificates and I selected the Trusted Root but don't have an option for which store.

Comment: Look at "Adding certificates to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store for a local computer" section from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx

Comment: Thanks bud, that's exactly what it was. Quick answer, great resources provided.